# Adding TextView dynamically in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, eclipse

i am using following code. The code should show values of values in a row e.g if the `values[]` contain `{A,B,C,D,E,F}` It should show `A B C D E F` In `relative layout`. If i don't use `LayoutParams pramas` then all `textViews` are added over each other. How can i make them add to the left of each other

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < values.length ; i++)
      {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(values[i].toString());
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setId(i);
        textView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        textView.setTextSize(24);
        LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LayoutParams params  = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 50, 0, 0); 
        if (i>0)
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, i);
        textView.setLayoutParams(param);
        wordsLayout.addView(textView,params);
      }
    }
```

The problem is, when i use  `wordsLayout.addView(textView,params);` Nothing is displayed

Comment: I'm sorry, but don't you want `RIGHT_OF`? or do you want `{A,B,C,D,E,F}` to display as `F E D C B A` ?

Comment: sorry, i have changed it to Right of but when i use params of relative layout, nothing is displayed. That is the problem. Problem edited

Comment: Are you declaring two sets of LayoutParams in your actual code? you should only be using one, so don't declare param and don't apply it to the textView.  It could be that param is overwriting params when android adds the view to the viewgroup

Comment: Tried removing pram of textView, It didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U R WORKING CODE...

```
LinearLayout wordsLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
        {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            textView.setClickable(true);
            textView.setId(i);
            textView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
            textView.setTextSize(24);
            LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LayoutParams params  = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 50, 0, 0); 
            if (i>0)
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, i);
            textView.setLayoutParams(param);
            wordsLayout.addView(textView,params);
        }

        setContentView(wordsLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting each Textview inside its own Viewgroup which wraps around the Textviews content size. Have all the Viewgroups lined up next to each other the way you want all the visible textviews do. And make the inner textview-elements VISIBLE and GONE however you need to have them displayed. It's the least messy way of doing it in my opinion, and it secures the order of your textviews.